# Windows 10 won't save speaker balance

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers

As described in a plethora of online forums, Windows 10 just can't seem to save the balance that is inputted by users:

[image]

For whatever reason this issue seems to have persisted since the inception of Windows 10, and has not been resolved AFAIK. So my question is as follows:

Is there a way to issue command-line commands to set the audio output balance in Windows 10? I'm thinking `.bat` script, or [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to run at startup since Windows has so much trouble saving a simple value.

I would also be open to registry workarounds if anyone knows how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a gem of a program (totally free) which is a super useful Windows Utility that has command line support for adjusting the balance of the speakers. This means we can incorporate this to load at startup.

The Utility is called **Sound Volume View** and be downloaded [HERE](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html)

There is a short tutorial on how to use the command line features [HERE](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/set-audio-balance-command-line.html)

The `.bat` script I created is simple:

```
pushd "PATH TO YOUR SoundValueView exe DIR"

SoundVolumeView.exe /SetVolumeChannels "NAME OF YOUR SOUND DEVICE" 30 37
```

The 30 is the left side and the 37 is the right side. Adjust these values to your personal preference.

To have this run at startup I created a shortcut for the .bat script and placed it in the following directories:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```